# To close dialog component based on api response

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I have component called `AddCustomerComponent` which i am calling as dialog component,In the `AddCustomerComponent` after filling the input fields i am performing **POST** operation.Now POST operation working fine.

**But after `POST` operation based on the api response, I want perform following operations:**

- If POST is successful,then **dialog(AddCustomerComponent)** should close.
- If not,then dialog should not close.

Below are my **component** code and **service** file codes:

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="addForm">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="name" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="addCusForm.controls.name.hasError('required')">
            Please enter your name
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input placeholder="Email Address"  formControlName="email" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="addCusForm.controls.email.hasError('required') ">
            Please enter email address
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-flat-button  type="submit" (click)="onAddCustomer()">Save</button>
    <button mat-flat-button  type="button">Cancel</button>  
</form>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { ICustomer } from 'src/app/models/app.models';
import { CustomersService } from 'src/app/services/customers.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'awa-add-customer',
  templateUrl: './add-customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-customer.component.css'],
})
export class AddCustomerComponent implements OnInit {
  public addForm: FormGroup;
  public someCustomer: ICustomer;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    public customersService: CustomersService,
  ) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [null,[Validators.required]],
      email: [null,[Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  public onAddCustomer(): void {
    this.someCustomer = this.addForm.value;
    this.customersService.addCustomer(this.someCustomer);
  }

}
```

**Service Fle**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ICustomer } from 'src/app/models/app.models';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class CustomersService {
 private  baseUrl : string = '....api URL.....';

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public async addCustomer(customer: ICustomer ): Promise<void>  {
    const apiUrl: string = `${this.baseUrl}/customers`;
    let temp : any;
    temp =  this.http.post(apiUrl, customer).subscribe(data => {
        alert('Customer added successfully');
    },error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: return the promise from the service and handle the response/error in you component with `then()`, `catch()`

Comment: Why are you setting all of the methods as public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply have to return the promise of the Post call from your service, and subscribe to it to close the dialog wheter or not the http call has gone well.

First, don't forget to return your promise in the service method:

```
public addCustomer(customer: ICustomer ): Promise<void>  {
  const apiUrl: string = `${this.baseUrl}/customers`;
  return this.http.post(apiUrl, customer);
  // I removed the subscribe() here since you can have only one per promise
  // But you can use Rxjs 'pipe' operation if necessary.
}
```

Then, subscribe to the promise when calling the `addCustomer()` method:

```
public onAddCustomer(): void {
  this.someCustomer = this.addForm.value;
  this.customersService.addCustomer(this.someCustomer).subscribe(
    () => // POST is ok, close dialog,
    (error) => // do nothing, or alert
  );
}
```

---

**EDIT:**
The previous snippet has been deprecated and will be removed in RxJS v8. Docs: https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments
The new suggested method is to use an object parameter to specify which callback to use.

```
public onAddCustomer(): void {
   this.someCustomer = this.addForm.value;
   this.customersService.addCustomer(this.someCustomer).subscribe({
      next: (v) => console.log(v),
      error: (e) => console.error(e),
      complete: () => console.info('complete') 
   });
}
```

If you only use the `next` callback, it is recommended to simply pass in an anonymous function:

```
public onAddCustomer(): void {
   this.someCustomer = this.addForm.value;
   this.customersService.addCustomer(this.someCustomer).subscribe((v) => console.log(v));
}
```

Comment: Your solution works fine, thank for the ans, But If i add `Promise<void>` in `addCustomer`  method in `service` file.it showing this lint error: **[ts] Type 'Observable<Object>' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<void>': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag]**

Comment: I removed the `async` keyword from your method, since you didn't used `await` when calling it. `async` automatically returns a Promise, now you return an `Observable` :) If you prefer to use Promises, you should try to call `this.http.post(...).toPromise()`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to close the dialog reference.I think observable is a good choice.
You service could be like this.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ICustomer } from 'src/app/models/app.models';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class CustomersService {
 private  baseUrl : string = '....api URL.....';

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public async addCustomer(customer: ICustomer ): Observable<any>  {
    const apiUrl: string = `${this.baseUrl}/customers`;
    let temp : any;
    return this.http.post(apiUrl, customer);
  }

}
```

Your component will look like this.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { ICustomer } from 'src/app/models/app.models';
import { CustomersService } from 'src/app/services/customers.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'awa-add-customer',
  templateUrl: './add-customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-customer.component.css'],
})
export class AddCustomerComponent implements OnInit {
  public addForm: FormGroup;
  public someCustomer: ICustomer;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddCustomerComponent>
    public customersService: CustomersService,
  ) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [null,[Validators.required]],
      email: [null,[Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  public onAddCustomer(): void {
    this.someCustomer = this.addForm.value;


  this.customersService.addCustomer(this.someCustomer).subscribe((respons)=>{
   // validate the response here and then close the dialog
    // after successfull adding customer
    this.dialogRef.close();
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: Please read my question completely,I want close dialog `based upon api response`,I know how to close the dialog on clicking the `button`.

Comment: Okay let me try.

Answer (score 1):

you should work with the promise returned from the service.

```
public onAddCustomer(): void {
this.someCustomer = this.addForm.value;
this.customersService.addCustomer(this.someCustomer)
  .then(
    // add success code here
  )
  .catch(
    // add error code here
  )
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Here instead of subscribing in a service file, subscribe in your component so that you can apply your conditions like below.

**Service.ts**

```
 public addCustomer(customer: ICustomer ) : Observable<any>  {
    const apiUrl: string = `${this.baseUrl}/customers`;
    return this.http.post(apiUrl, customer);
  }
```

**component.ts**

```
 public onAddCustomer(): void {
    this.someCustomer = this.addForm.value;
    this.customersService.addCustomer(this.someCustomer).subscribe(data => {
        alert('Customer added successfully');
        this.dialogRef.close();
    },error => {
    // do not close dialog when error.
        console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Hope this help!